# How to get a specific link for web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm writing a program to get the market value of soccer players and it works

```
from bs4 import *
import requests

def marketvalue():

reply = str(input("Enter the player whose current market value you wish to know \n"))

url = ("http://www.transfermarkt.com/en/first-last/profil/playerid.html")

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

mydivs = soup.findAll("td", {"class" : "note"})

value = str(mydivs[0].get_text())

print("Current value of {0} is {1}".format(reply, value))
```

The problem is that the URL for the player is based on the playerid which is seemingly random. Is there anyway to get this using requests or soup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import mechinize
http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/documentation.html
Using this along with BeautifulSoup should provide you with the results
you are looking for.
More Docs.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/l-python-mechanize-beautiful-soup/index.html?ca=dat